# Filtrar dos columnas en sqlalchemy usando python+flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Tengo una aplicación flask, y una tabla con dos columnas, una para la fecha y otra para la hora. Tengo un formulario de citas y quiero comprobar si la fecha+hora ya se ha tomado. Mi módulo es así:

---

```
form = DateForm() 

if form.validate_on_submit(): 

    if Appointment.query.filter_by(date=form.date.data).filter_by(hour=form.hour.data):
```

Pero parece que el único filtro que acepta es el de la fecha, ya que me sube el mensaje de flash aunque la hora esté libre: es decir, me rechaza por la fecha. ¿Alguna sugerencia de cómo se puede filtrar también la columna de la hora? Mi objetivo es rechazar si por ejemplo en mi tabla existe 10/12/2021 10:00 pero aceptar si las 11:00 está disponible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pude solucionar el problema con la siguiente modificación:

```py
if Appointment.query.filter( and_( Appointment.date.like(form.date.data), Appointment.hour.like(form.hour.data.strftime('%H:%M')) ) ).first():
```

Comment: Explica brevemente qué hace tu código, y dale formato colocando triples acentos graves (```) una línea antes y una línea después del mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar

```
 Appointment.query.filter(Appointment.date==form.date.data, Appointment.hour == form.hour.data).all()
```

Si necesitas filtrar por fecha y hora yo haría

```
Appointment.query.filter(Appointment.date.between(fecha1, fecha2)).all()
```